# How to fix Http Status 404 Not found?

Tags: java, spring

I've just started with Spring framework, currently learning the spring MVC the configuration is just too complicated xD , anyway everytime i try to run the application on the server it gives me this page instead of main-menu.jsp page.

I've tried to add the @RequestMapping("/") to the method in my controller calss and the method should return a String as u can see in the code below

[image: Project Tree]
[image: The result]
HompePage.java

```
@Controller
public class HomePage {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
```

main-menu.jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Spring MVC Demo - Home Page</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servelet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Ayoub.springdemo.mvc" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>  
   <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

I've got Http status 404 - Not found

Logs

```
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.24
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 14 2019 21:16:42 UTC
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.24.0
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.18.0-25-generic
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           12.0.1+12
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/ayoub/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/ayoub/Desktop/apache-tomcat-9.0.24
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/ayoub/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/ayoub/Desktop/apache-tomcat-9.0.24
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/ayoub/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [3,226] milliseconds
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 05, 2019 3:37:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1,524] milliseconds
```

Comment: how are you accessing the application? do you have a code posted somewhere on Github? if not, then please share the logs.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare what do u mean bu the logs

Comment: eclipse console output.

Comment: There you go sorry i didn't post it here coz it is so long so :

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kR7ocnkJpKZOP5y5ds1xA2GP78BrisnN

Comment: It seems that web.xml is not correct, it should start with"<web-app" and define DispatcherServlet and servlet mapping

Comment: Example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: i've tried it with the web.xml in the link but  same problem sorry for the delay

Comment: any update pleas ? i've been stuck in this issue for almost a day

Comment: How do you deploy your application ? Can you add your deployment logs too ?

Comment: is it what u r looking for @ArnaudClaudel 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kR7ocnkJpKZOP5y5ds1xA2GP78BrisnN/view

Comment: I don't know, please add it directly in the question instead of a google drive link

Comment: you got it chief

Comment: Add your spring application.properties to the question

Comment: @ZacharyCraig do u mean the jar files ??

Comment: do you a have a repo where the project could be cloned?

Comment: Without complete logs hard to figure out the issue but you can try adding this to your web.xml and see if it works <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>main-menu.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

Comment: still got the same issue guys i've tried almost everything i cound upload the project on github if that possible i can provide u with the link

Comment: https://github.com/ayoubsouid/spring-mvc-demo..git

Answer (score 0):

your web.xml should be like this you have to give servelt name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>  
   <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>



@Controller
public class HomePage {
    @RequestMapping("/main-menu")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
```

Comment: spring-mvc-demo-servelet.xml change this name to spring-servlet.xml and follow folder structure it will work refer https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Comment: same issue mate thank you anyway for ur answer but i've tried even to download the project from jvtpoint and run it i got the same problem